# Android CordovaWebView TIMEOUT ERROR

Tags: android, cordova

Seems like this question is old and many would have asked.Yet,I didn't get a perfect solution.

I have tried by setting the Integer property, with "loadUrlTimeoutValue", 10000. Yet it still show problem.

Does it causes of because of phone's memory ?

Please help me to fix the issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of cordova ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new main html

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title>tittle</title>
   <script>
     window.location='./ur_html_file.html';
   </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

in your java code:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/main.html");
```